# sliding menu over tab and fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Working with slidingmenu and actionbarsherloc. I want to show slidingmenu in left above the tab navigation and below the actionbar. As i want actiobar will remain fixed and tab and fragment will go aside to give room sliding menu. Is it possible with these duo??? Here is my code.

```
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.menu_shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.9f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
```

Comment: In case you don't find a solution and can switch libraries, I am using MenuDrawer (https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) and it has an example app implementing that.

Answer (score 1):

The tabs are part of the Action Bar and therefore it is not possible to do what you want using that component. It is however possible if you use the library [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to display the tabs instead.